# How do I append an item in a list to another list one at a time using for loop?

Tags: python, list

It seems simple, I cannot figure it out.
I have two lists

```
li = ['abc','def']
se = ['q1','q2','q3']
```

if I use for loop to join two lists, the result is not what I wanted.

```
for x in se:
   li.append(se)
   print(li)
```

My desired output would be **['abc','def','q1'], ['abc','def','q2'],['abc','def','q3']** Any ideas? Appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```py
li = ['abc','def']
se = ['q1','q2','q3']

new_lst = [li+[x] for x in se]
print(new_lst)
```

Output:

```py
[['abc', 'def', 'q1'], ['abc', 'def', 'q2'], ['abc', 'def', 'q3']]
```

Comment: This will probably be the most efficient answer. Maybe slicing `se` and using `range` (`new_lst = [li+se[i:i+1] for i in range(len(se))]`) could be used instead of creating a new list for each element (`[x]`) but I'm not sure if that would increase the performance.

Comment: Appreciated, I was stuck actually.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension, but if you wanted to use a `for-loop` `append` for simplicity you could use the code below.

```
li = ['abc','def']
se = ['q1','q2','q3']
res = []

for x in se:
  res.append(li + [x])
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[['abc', 'def', 'q1'], ['abc', 'def', 'q2'], ['abc', 'def', 'q3']]
```

Comment: I disagree with upvoting all working answers. Accepting one should be done but a general upvote should not be done. Votes are there to reflect the quality of answers , to hightlight very good answers or lowlight very bad answers. Voting simply evey answer does not help to differentiate between good and bad.

Answer (score 0):

`append` modifies the previous list so we need to make a copy (`li[:]` is the easiest way to make a copy of `li`) and also you need toa ppend `x` which is the element not `se` which is the other list:

```py
li = ['abc','def']
se = ['q1','q2','q3']

for x in se:
    li2 = li[:]
    li2.append(x)
    print(li2)
```

Output:

```py
['abc', 'def', 'q1']
['abc', 'def', 'q2']
['abc', 'def', 'q3']
```

Comment: @solid.py and what do you think that the `+` operator does?

Comment: li2 is a copy, for large datasets, it is not good performance-wise. I prefer the list comprehension way, very pythonic. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @LiuYu list comprehension replaces the for loop and is a bit better performace wise. But a copy is being created in all solutions. When you do `li + [x]` you are creating a copy of `li`, and then using `list.extend([x])` which is probably slightly worse performance wise than `list.append(x)`. So I do agree on you with the list comprehension part but do not mistakely think that that soultion is not making a copy.

Comment: I had no idea no idea that li + [x] creates a copy. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
li = ['abc', 'def']
se = ['q1', 'q2','q3']

for i in se:
    print(li + [i])
```

Output:

```
['abc', 'def', 'q1']
['abc', 'def', 'q2']
['abc', 'def', 'q3']
```

Or Try this:

```
li = ['abc', 'def']
se = ['q1', 'q2', 'q3']

result = [li + [i] for i in se]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['abc', 'def', 'q1'], ['abc', 'def', 'q2'], ['abc', 'def', 'q3']]
```